# Como buscar um ficheiro a um servidor interno?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um servidor a correr em casa, onde guardo alguns ficheiros. Eu queria ter na minha página, que está num servidor externo, uma forma de ir buscar esses ficheiro. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso em PHP?

Comment: Veja se isto lhe ajuda: http://www.revistaphp.com.br/artigo.php?id=48

Comment: Que tipo de software roda neste seu servidor local?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso específico iria talvez por utilizar soluções já existentes como por exemplo o OwnCloud.

Este dispõe de uma característica que dá pelo nome de **External storage support** e com ele podes referenciar ficheiros alojados em outros pontos como por exemplo:

```
Local
Amazon S3
Dropbox
FTP
Google Drive
OpenStack Object Storage
SMB/CIFS
ownCloud/WebDAV
SFTP
iRODS
```

Para o OwnCloud externo chegar ao servidor de casa pode ser por FTP se não for solução instalar também o OwnCloud no servidor de casa. Se for possível, então ficará mais fácil. Analisa!

**Dito isto, e com PHP como solicita a pergunta?** O script ao ser executado no servidor externo poderá com o CURL obter uma lista por directório a cada *click*. Com a lista virá os links aos mesmos.

Para colocar alguma segurança, cria uma estrutura para uma API e com OAUTH autoriza os acessos. Um pouco de trabalho, mas não será difícil de fazer pois estamos a falar de um serviço online para uso pessoal onde a exigência não será certamente muita.